# Wrong email id on letter of recommendation

Tags: recommendation-letter

My professor has entered the wrong email id into my letter of recommendation, gmail.com rather than yahoo.com and signed it. Can it be corrected using white ink? My college is very far away from my home and a reprinting would be extremely difficult. Would corrections on letter of recommendation hurt my application?

Comment: Is the mistake in the professor's email address, or yours, or something else?

Comment: In my professors email address
In the last line which says that if you need additional information regarding the recommendation contact me at

Comment: Have you confirmed whether it is a mistake? It would be unusual for somebody to fill out their own e-mail incorrectly. It's entirely possible that they own both e-mail addresses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never ever manipulate a letter written by a third person.

Explain the discrepancy, yes. You have to hope they accept the explanation.

However, if you manipulate, you are committing fraud, breach of trust, and you will be blacklisted where this is possible. You may also lose your recommender for the future if he gets to hear about that (e.g. if they manage to check with him). In some countries (such as Germany), manipulating official documents is explicitly a crime and can be punished with years in prison.

Comment: Would I be better off getting an entirely new letter of recommendation?

Comment: @HrishikeshBorkar Yes, if you can. If it's the professor's contact, you may just want to add a comment in a separate note that this was a typo in the letter (although, are you allowed to see your own letter of recommendation)?

Comment: It may also not matter at all -- the chances that anyone is going to contact the professor (and can't find their email address online if necessary) are essentially zero. You're just worrying too much :-)